# How to check which Button is pressed/unpressed with IF - Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, mouseevent

I want to check if four on-screen buttons are being pressed/released using 2 eventListeners and 2 functions, I know I can make each button press/unpress point to a different function but that leaves me 8 eventListeners and 8 functions in total, the CODE shown here I could make it work using keyboard keys instead of buttons (changing mouseEvent to keyboardEvent etc) but I need it to be buttons

All my buttons have different instances for each one, they are all inside another big instance.

Using keyboard I filled the (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE) with (event.keycode == EXAMPLE.KEY) so it worked perfectly.

but I need to know how to change (KEYBOARD_KEY_BEING_PRESSED) to (INSTANCE_OF_BUTTON_BEING_PRESSED)

Is there any way to achieve this? or I have to make the whole thing in other way?

CODE:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePressed);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);

function mousePressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonOnePressed = true;
    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonTwoPressed = true;

    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonThreePressed = true;

    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonFourPressed = true;
    }

}

function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonOnePressed = false;
    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonTwoPressed = false;

    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonThreePressed = false;

    }
    else if (I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE)
    {
        buttonFourPressed = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Event.currentTarget`, which is the object which most recently dispatched the event (`Event.target` is the original dispatcher of the event). So you check if `Event.currentTarget` is equal to each button.

Example (not a working set of code, but it will give you an idea of how to do this)

```
var btn1:Sprite, btn2:Sprite, btn3:Sprite, btn4:Sprite;
function mouseDownHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (e.currentTarget == btn1) {

    }
    else if (e.currentTarget == btn2) {

    }
    else if (e.currentTarget == btn3) {

    }
    else if (e.currentTarget == btn4) {

    }
}
```

[`Event.currentTarget`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) documentation